# Shopping cart Python

Tags: python, function

I've noticed that when I remove a item, I need to select the checkout option multiple times.
Anybody know why this is happening?

```
my_cart = []

def customerDecision(addItem, input1):
  while True:
    customerResponse = input("What would you like to do? add / remove / show / checkout / quit ")
    if customerResponse.lower() == "add":
      addItem = input('add what? ')
      my_cart.append(addItem) 
      
    elif customerResponse.lower() == "show":
      print(my_cart)
   
    elif customerResponse.lower() == "remove":
      input1 = input(f'remove what: {my_cart} ')
      print(f'{input1} removed...')

    elif input1 in my_cart:
      my_cart.remove(input1)
      
    elif customerResponse.lower() == "checkout":
      for addItem in my_cart:
        print(f"Thanks for purchasing {my_cart}: '\n'see you next time!")
        break

    elif customerResponse.lower() == "quit":
      print("Thank you! We hope you find what you're looking for next time")
      break

    else:
      print("Please try a valid command.")

customerDecision(addItem='', input1='')
```

Comment: You have an indentation problem.  The `elif input1 in my_cart:` should not be an elif.  It should be an `if` that is PART of the previous statement.  You only want to do that if they entered "remove".

Comment: `elif input1 in my_cart:` it should be only `if` instead of `elif`, and it should be indented same as `print(f'{input1} removed...')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
    elif customerResponse.lower() == "remove":
      input1 = input(f'remove what: {my_cart} ')
      if input1 in my_cart:
        my_cart.remove(input1)
        print(f'{input1} removed...')
```

By the way, it would be more efficient if you said

```
    customerResponse = customerResponse.lower()
```

once at the top, rather than calling that function 5 times.